# Calling a Javascript function from HTML

Tags: php, javascript, html, xmlhttprequest

I am having a HTML table with 5 rows (say) which is being displayed on the webpage. The first column of the table is **RowID** (which is unique for each row) and the last column of each row is a **[X]** button (which on click will remove the row). The whole table is in a **`<div>`** element with `id="cartmain"`

```
<div id="cartmain">
     <table>
          <tr>
            <td>....</td>
            <td>....</td>
            <td> <a href="#" onclick="removeitem('id1')"> [X] </a> </td>
          </tr>
          ..
          ..
     </table>
</div>
```

This is how I am removing the row:

**STEP1:** When user clicks on [X] button, an XMLHTTPRequest function will send message to a PHP code with unique id of each row. During the time PHP code is removing the row, DIV element shows "Loading..."

`document.getElementById("cartmain").innerHTML = "Loading..."`

**STEP2:** PHP code will delete the row from table (and from database) and will return the remaining table.

```
<?php
     //removing row from database/table...

     //send the remaining table back to the XMLHTTPRequest function...
     echo "<table>";
     echo "<tr><td>...</td>
               <td>...</td>
               <td> <a href=\"#\" onclick=\"removeitem('id1')\"> [X] </a> </td>";
     echo "</tr>";
     ...
     ...
     ...
     echo "</table>";
?>
```

This remaining table received from the PHP code is then shown in the DIV element by using the below line:

`document.getElementById("cartmain").innerHTML = removeitem.responseText;`

**My Problem:**
Suppose I have table with 5 rows. When I click on the Remove button, the row is removed successfully and table is then displayed with 4 remaining rows. Here comes the problem: When I want to remove another row from the table: Nothing is Happening. In other words, if I again click on **[X]** of some row **then nothing happens**. The XMLHTTPRequest function is not called. In ideal case, it should have called the XMLHTTPRequest function again with that unique RowID and table should then be displayed with remaining 3 rows.

IMPORTANT NOTE: When I refresh the page, then I am able to remove another row. But this time also, I can remove only one row. For removing one more, I have to refresh the page again.

Is anyone able to identify the problem here? Please help.

NOTE: My table actually is a Shopping Cart which contains a product in each row. **[X]** button actually signifies "removing the item" from the cart.

Here is the JavaScript code:

```
function removeitem(itemid)
{
    alert("The item to be removed is: "+itemid);
    if(window.XMLHttpRequest)
    {
        removeitem = new XMLHttpRequest();
    }
    else
    {
        removeitem=new ActiveXObject("Microsoft.XMLHTTP");
    }

    removeitem.onreadystatechange=function()
    {
        if (removeitem.readyState==4 && removeitem.status==200)
        {
            document.getElementById("cartmain").innerHTML=removeitem.responseText;
        }
        else if(removeitem.readyState < 4)
        {
            document.getElementById("cartmain").innerHTML="Loading...";
        }
    }
    var linktoexecute = "cart.php?option=5&itemid="+itemid; //option =5 signifies that I want to remove the item with ITEMID.
    removeitem.open("GET",linktoexecute,true);
    removeitem.send();
}
```

The function removeitem shows an alert "The item to be removed is: 123" for the first time but does not shows second time. When I am checking in Firebug console, the following error is coming second time:

**removeitem is not a function**

Please help!!

All my Javascript functions are in a separate file (sc.js) for which I am using `<script type="text/javascript" src="js/sc.js"></script>` in the `HEAD` tag of my page.

My viewpoint: So finally I think the question comes to a simple point: If a webpage is requesting some HTML from a PHP page using XMLHTTPRequest -- and if that HTML (sent by PHP) contains some button which is calling a Javascript function -- then what will happen in this situation[?]. Now since I am able to remove the row for the first time, I think it is false to say that above situation will not work. It is just that the code that came from PHP and the Javascript which has already been loaded are not aware of each others presence when I click the button second time.

Comment: Your PHP code shows an error in quotation marks. Use `<a href=\"#\" onclick=\"removeitem('id1')\"> [X] </a> </td>`. Also, you have to show relevant (JavaScript) code if you expect help.

Comment: Hi Rob: I am using with \ only. Just that I forgot to mention it here. Edited the question! :)

Comment: Your updated question still contains several quotation issues. Are you sure that your code is working, even at the first click? Check your error console, or post a link to your website.

Comment: Hi Rob, It is working perfectly on the first click. Can you please tell me which part is having quotation issues? Is it javascript or PHP? I will edit it quickly and let you know the response. Thank you. PS: My website is on my local system.

Comment: Hi Rob, I found out which quotation error you are saying. Edited again. Is there anymore quotation errors? :)

Comment: Hav a look at the generated source, and compare these. Does function `removeitem` disappear at some point? Is any JavaScript error thrown at the console? Is the JavaScript being loaded at the second case?

Comment: Hi Rob, as I mentioned earlier -- the HTML sent by PHP code is correct. The only error thrown at the console (when I click second time) is `removeitem is not a function`. Javascript is only loaded when I refresh the page, during subsequent removing of the items -- page is not being refreshed by me.

Comment: I have found your error, after looking again. I will post the answer :p

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Inside the `removeitem` function, you're overwriting `removeitem` by a `XMLHttpRequest` object. Hence the later error `removeitem is not a function`.

To fix this, either prefix `removeitem` by var (recommended), or use another variable name, or both.

Recommended code:

```
function removeitem(itemid) {
    alert("The item to be removed is: "+itemid);
    var removeitem = window.XMLHttpRequest ? new XMLHttpRequest() : new ActiveXObject("Microsoft.XMLHTTP");

    removeitem.onreadystatechange = function() {
        if (removeitem.readyState == 4 && removeitem.status == 200) {
            document.getElementById("cartmain").innerHTML = removeitem.responseText;
        } else if(removeitem.readyState < 4) {
            document.getElementById("cartmain").innerHTML="Loading...";
        }
    }
    var linktoexecute = "cart.php?option=5&itemid="+itemid; //option =5 signifies that I want to remove the item with ITEMID.
    removeitem.open("GET", linktoexecute, true);
    removeitem.send();
}
```

Adding `var` before `removeitem` fixes the problem, because the variable is locally defined. When `var` is omitted, a new value will be attached to the closest parent declaration (the function, in this case).

```
var removeitem = window.XMLHttpRequest ? new XMLHttpRequest() : new ActiveXObject("Microsoft.XMLHTTP");
```

The previous line is short for:

```
var removeitem;
if (window.XMLHttpRequest) {
    removeitem = new XMLHttpRequest();
} else {
    removeitem = new ActiveXObject("Microsoft.XMLHTTP");
}
```

Answer (score 2):

it doesn't look like  you're escaping your double quotes like @Rob W has stated.  I generally use single quotes when using php to write out HTML.  I find this to be a good practice in my opinion.

The only other thing I can think of is that maybe your function isn't outside AJAX response text.  Just check Firebug or view source of what's being rendered after the first response returned.

I hope this helps.

Comment: ok based on your edited question, is your Javascript function outside of the response text, like it's rendered on the page load, and not on each AJAX response, because this will be an issue.  also, another note, you should have a semicolon like so and return false to keep the page from jumping: `onclick=\"removeitem('id1'); return false;\"`

Comment: Hi Robert. Thank you the comment. Can you tell me what do you mean by saying "function isn't outside AJAX response text" ?

Comment: meaning your function (ie removeitem()) isn't a part of the response text and is rendered on the initial page load.

Comment: The function `removeitem()` is in another file `sc.js`. This file I have included by using `<script type="text/javascript" src="js/sc.js"></script>` in the HEAD tag. Is this the problem? Is this correct? Should I put my function in HEAD tag instead of a separate file?

Comment: are you seeing the alert message regarding the delete after you remove a row?

Comment: When I first click the remove button, I am getting the alert message. 
After the row has been removed, when I click it second time, I do not get any alert message. 
Then I refresh the page and then click on remove item then I get alert message. This means that during the second time the XHR function is not called.

Comment: k, so based on this, i'd check your HTML and how it's rendered after the first AJAX post; also check firebug for any errors, this will help to identify the issue.

Answer (score 2):

Why you load all table html every click? You can send only true or false when deleting and after you can remove TR element with jQuery.

Removing TR:
In your `removeitem` function, after ajax response, just call `$(this).parents("tr").remove();`

Comment: Thanks Cesar. As I mentioned, it is a shopping cart application. When an item is removed from cart, it involves many other things like updating the "Total Amount", revised "Shipping Charges", total items in cart etc (and all this without refreshing the page). If I send only true or false then I will have to make many many other changes. Right now my concern is `Why my code is not able to find the removeitem function? Why it is able to remove item in the first time but not second?`