# How do i call a function from an external html document?

Tags: html

So what i want to do is call a "function" from an external document into my webpages, similar to how in C++ you can create a header file and place your functions there, link it back to your main program and call the functions at will.

I need to make the website with changing it in mind, and my thoughts were to have the nav bar/menu separate so that it can be tweaked without having to go to each page and copy in the new code, as this is obviously time consuming.

Ive tried using an iframe, but it created more problems than it solved, as when a link was pressed the new webpage opened inside the iframe, which isn't what i wanted.

is there a method doing this or am i going to have to leave it?

Comment: You can't... Though if it's a Javascript function, then simply place it in it's own .js file, and load it into multiple .html files by using the `<script>` tag.

Comment: possible duplicate of [Calling a Javascript function from HTML](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/8289505/calling-a-javascript-function-from-html)

Comment: I think what you're actually asking is **how do I include the same chunk of HTML in all pages of my site**

Comment: Back in the bad old days we used to do that sort of thing with frames (not iFrames) and you got what you wanted to happen by setting the target property on the link tag.

Comment: You may want to learn about SSI

Comment: You're serving HTML files via....IIS?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You just need to create a JavaScript file, like `my-filename.js` and put your JavaScript code in it. Then in your html document, do this:

```
<script src="path/to/my-filename.js"></script>
```

Now you can make changes in that file and it will be updated anywhere you have included it with the `script` tag.